# Images in vue-cli causing issues. Node- Express, mysql backend

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, nginx

I have some code that uploads images to a folder on my server and stores a reference in a mysql database. All was fine in development, but trying to work with production my images are undefined and 404 error results.

I found the documentation, [VUE Static Files](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#html) But I am struggling with this setup, as I have another server set up as an NGINX proxy server, so all my traffic goes there first. I have tried using relative paths. Storing the full path in my database, just the file name, and trying to work that into my server and build for production. For example I am trying to figure out how to use assets to house image files that will be there when uploaded from the back-end.

If I just focus on the frontend, my backend server has uploaded an image file to this the /dist/img/ folder and I wand to reference that in the frontend vue files.

```
<template>
    <div class="ui link cards">
        <div class="card" id="custom-card">
            <div class="ui header">Today's Feed</div>
            <button class="ui button" id="sub-button" @click="showTodaysItems">Submit</button>
            <button class="ui button" @click="clearReport">Clear</button>
        </div>

            <hr>
            <div class="ui container response-modal modal"  id="report-modal" v-if="reportData.length >= 1">
                <div class="ui header">Todays Items</div>
                <i id="close-icon" class="big close icon right top" @click.prevent="onClose"></i>
                <div class="ui  devided items">
                    <div class="item" id="report-item" v-for="(item, index) in reportData" :key="`item-${index}`"  @click="showItem(item)" >
                        <div>
                        {{item.description}}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        {{item.notes}}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        {{item.commodity}}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        {{item.sampleDate}}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        {{item.carrier}}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        {{item.shipper}}
                        </div>
                         <div v-if="item.approve == 1">
                            Approved
                        </div>
                        <div v-else>
                            Rejected
                        </div>
                        <img class="ui tiny image" :src="getImageUrl(item.image)">
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    const API_REPORTS_ENDPOINT = "localhost/api/reports/";
    import axios from 'axios';
    const todaysDate = new Date();
    let dd = String(todaysDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    let mm = String(todaysDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    let yyyy = todaysDate.getFullYear();
    var todayFormatedDate = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            today: {
                todaysDate: todayFormatedDate,
            }, 
            reportData: [],
            showSelectedTodaysItems: false,
            selectedItem: {},
        }
    },
    name: 'reports',
    methods: {
        showTodaysItems(event) {
            axios.post(API_REPORTS_ENDPOINT + 'todaysFeed',
                    this.today,
                    { headers: {
                        'Content-type' : 'application/json',
                    }
                    }).then(response => {
                        this.reportData = response.data.data;
                }).catch(error => {console.log(error)}); 
        },
        showItem(i) {
            this.selectedItem = i;
            this.showSelectedTodaysItems = true;
        },
        closeTodaysItems() {
            this.selectedItem = {};
            this.showSelectedTodaysItems = false;
        },
        clearReport() {
            this.reportData = {};
        },
        onClose() {
            this.reportData = {};
            this.showSelectedRangeItems = false;
        },
        getImageUrl(image) {
            return require('../../../public/images/'+ image)
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

My issue is where I am requiring the image file worked in development, but everything got minified and moved around for production, I don't fully understand how to fix this based on the docs, I have tried, using '/assets/' like that, using base url, but it's not making much sense, could there be an easier way to handle this.

Comment: As an addition to the response from @Phil. Which helped in terms of Vue code, I needed to add a reference for express static since I am using node to serve the site in production. Adding app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/img')); Plus Vue code below resolved the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are in the `public` directory, you don't need `require`, you can reference them directly since everything in the `public` directory is bundled as-is.

For example, add the `BASE_URL` to your data properties...

```js
data() {
  return {
    publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL,
    // etc
  }
}
```

and in your template

```html
<img class="ui tiny image" :src="`${publicPath}images/${item.image}`">
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

---

FYI, having method calls like `getImageUrl()` in your templates is very inefficient and should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a two-part issue. The help above on the vue side was great by @Phil. One line of code needed to be added in Node/ Express  to expose the images on the backend.

```
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/img'));
```

After doing both the images were available in production.